# C++ Class Files

Tags: c++, xcode, file, class

I am having much trouble learning to use files for classes in C++.  To learn I use Bucky Roberts/The New Boston C++ tutorials, I have tried exactly what he does, but it does not work.

I have the main.cpp and the OtherClass.cpp with the OtherClass.h for header.  Every time I try doing OtherClass::OtherClass(){} for the constructor it errors out with **"C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"**

Could someone give me an example of how to do C++ class files correctly?  Really confused right now.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: You won't learn much from him. Get a book

Comment: It sounds like you did not include the header file (OtherClass.h) in your implementation file (OtherClass.cpp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example of using header files for classes (with the implementation in a separate .cpp file) looks something like this:

Your main.cpp file:

```
#include "OtherClass.h"

int main()
{
  OtherClass otherClass;
  //use otherClass here...

}
```

Next, your OtherClass.h file:

```
class OtherClass
{
  public:
    OtherClass();

    int someFunction(int parameters);

};
```

And then finally your OtherClass.cpp file:

```
#include "OtherClass.h"

OtherClass::OtherClass() 
{
  //implementation here
}

int OtherClass::someFunction(int parameters)
{
  //implemenation here
  return 0; 
}
```

The main things to keep in mind:

- `#include "OtherClass.h"` goes in both OtherClass.cpp and main.cpp
- make sure you finish constructor and function declarations with ';' not '{}' if you are defining the implementation elsewhere.
- make sure you're compiling OtherClass.cpp as well as main.cpp. With MinGW this looks like `g++ main.cpp OtherClass.cpp`

Comment: Thanks this did the trick!  It appears Bucky's some of Bucky's videos are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little cryptic to understand, but if I understand correctly you're looking for the `correct' way to create classes with interfaces in the header file. Here is an example of a class that does this:

**Scene.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Window.h"
#include "Entity.h"

class Scene
{
public:
    Scene(Window *_window);
    ~Scene(void);

    void render(Entity item);
    void render(Entity item, SDL_Rect *clip);

protected:
    Window *window;
};
```

**Scene.cpp**

```
#include "Scene.h"


Scene::Scene(Window *_window)
{
    window = _window;
}


Scene::~Scene(void)
{

}

void Scene::render(Entity item) {
    render(item, NULL);
}

void Scene::render(Entity item, SDL_Rect *clip) {
    window->draw( item.getImage(), item.getCoordinates(), clip, item.getAngle() );
}
```

Notice that the header file includes the headers that it needs to link properly, while the implementation file (.cpp) just includes the header file. The linker should automatically manage all this trouble for you as long as you stick to these semantics.

I hope this helps; if it doesn't, consider rephrasing your question or pasting some code.